# First Boot Script for variety of platforms

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, boot

I'd like to make a firstboot script for CentOS 5/6 and Ubuntu 12.04/12.10/14.04. If possible, I'd like to use one method to trigger this script to run.

From what I can tell, this rules out `chkconfig`, `firstboot` file, upstarts jobs, etc. I'm a bit confused with the plethora of terminology/technology. Is there one method I can use for all these platforms that will run a small script on first boot (after other services is fine)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `/etc/rc.local`, it is present on all of the systems you mention. It is executed after all of the other initialisation scripts, see the comments in the file for more information.

Comment: Perfect! I noticed that `/etc/rc.local` is a symlink on CentOS, and for my purpose I had to update the original file at (`etc/rc.d/rc.local`)